# dismissViewControllerAnimated does not deallocate memory

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController A, in this point my memory its 104 Mb. In A, I open UIVIewController B normally like this:

```
UIViewController *b = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithLevel:level actualUser:actualUser parentViewController:self];
[self presentViewController:b animated:NO completion:nil];
```

At this point my memory its 132 Mb, then when the user touch a button i open UIViewController C like this:

```
UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithBlackboard:3];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    [parentViewController(i get this property in the init method) presentViewController:c animated:NO completion:nil];
}];
```

Here, what I do, is close B and then open C, so when I close C it leads me directly to A.

At this point my memory its a 153 Mb, which is wrong, because the memory of B never deallocates (frees). After this, I dismiss like this to return to A:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
```

And instead of having 104 Mb I have 132 Mb, so B was never released. The windows are opened and closed in the right way but the memory it's the problem.

I have tested each UIViewController separately and I didn't have any memory issues. The problem comes when they are bound together. Any ideas?

I have also looked out for memory leaks, and I haven't found any.

Comment: There are probably some strong references of `ViewControllerB` in your code

Comment: I set the parentViewController variable as __weak UIViewController

Comment: I mean `ViewControllerB` the one that not be dealloced. Not `ViewControllerA` which presenting `ViewControllerB`.

Comment: Let me double check it

Answer (score 4):

It's a circular reference.

```
@interface A : UIViewController {

              UIViewController* B;

          }

@end 

@interface B : UIViewController {

               UIViewController* A;

         }

@end
```

and if you use ARC with strong references or default,It makes memory leak..

The memory tool Instruments not always correct.In some Complex programs,To Log the retain count is a way to Check whether release correct.If you use ARC to manage memory,It is best to avoid circular reference.

This link is office ARC document,It is very detailed.
[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Just a little suggest.Best wishes!

Comment: The first sentence in the `retainCount` documentation: "Do not use this method."

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an id variable that i never "release" set to nil